# Specifics of calling a method from the Parent Class

Tags: c#, .net

My question is simple.

I am working with a testcase given to me in C#.

In this test case they have a Parent class containing all the methods and subclasses that will call those methods.

So as far as I know. You can do that by:
`Class object = new Class(arguments);`

Then call the parent methods like this `object.Method()`

Now the test I am working with has it written like this: `Class.Method()`

So just to make my question more clear here is an example of what they have:

`Book harryPotterBook = new Book { title = "Harry Potter" };`

`var savedBook = Book.Find(harryPotterBook.Id);`

and here is what I understand it should be:

`var savedBook = harryPotterBook.Find(harryPotterBook.Id);`

So is this possible? I just want to know what I am missing here.
Thank you.

Comment: If you did `myBook.Find(...)`  where `myBook` is an instance of the `Book` class, you would be calling an instance method.  If you are using `Book.Find(...)`, where `Book` is a `Type` that would be a static method. Further details [C# static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Comment: Note that `Book harryPotterBook = new Book { title = "Harry Potter" };` is not the same as `MyClass myObject = new MyClass(arguments);`. In the Harry Potter case, you are calling a default constructor (one with _no_ arguments) and then setting a _property_ (`title`). In the MyClass case, you are calling a constructor with at least one argument. They are very different

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do right now, because in your example, you seem to be asking how to generate a class with a constructor. If you want to create a class constructor you have to write it like this:

```
public class Class 
{
    string name;

    public Class(string pName) 
    {
        name = pName;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you know that this class is going to be used often as a standard. You can use interfaces:

```
interface IBasicClass 
{
    string name { get; set; }
    string description { get; set; }

    int numberOfPage { get; set; }
    int currentPage { get; set; }

    void NextPage();
    void PreviousPage();
}

public class BasicClass : IBasicClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public int numberOfPage { get; set; }
    public int currentPage { get; set; }

    //Default Constructor
    public BasicClass() 
    {
        name = "";
        description = "";

        numberOfPage = 0;
        currentPage = 0;
    }

    //Constructor
    public BasicClass(string pName, string pDescription, int pNumberOfPage) 
    {
        name = pName;
        description = pDescription;
        numberOfPage = pNumberOfPage;
    }

    public void PreviousPage()
    {
        --currentPage;
    }

    public void NextPage() 
    {
        ++currentPage;
    }
}

public class Class : MonoBehaviour 
{
    BasicClass _basicClass;
    BasicClass _basicClass2;

    void Start()
    {
        _basicClass = new BasicClass();
        _basicClass2 = new BasicClass("Books", "It's a good book", 1);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _basicClass.NextPage();
        _basicClass2.NextPage();
    }
}
```